# <Base> must be a previously defined class or struct

Tags: c++

I have a header and cpp file for a base class, and a header and cpp file for a derived class.  I am getting the below error in the header file of the derived class:

> `Base` must be a previously defined class or struct.

I have included the base class header file in the derived class header file. I realize that the definition of the base class isn't in the header file, but I read that including a cpp file isn't a good practice.  Also, if I put both class definitions in same header file and implement both classes in the same cpp file, there's no errors.

Since the code is for a school project, I will give the example, but not the exact code:

base.h

```
#ifndef _base_h_
#define _base_h_

#include "derived.h"

class Base {
public:

  void start();
  void waitToComplete();
  virtual ~Base();

  static void sleep(Time timeToSleep);

protected:

  friend class Derived;
  Base ();
  virtual void run() {}
};

#endif
```

derived.h

```
#ifndef _derived_h_
#define _derived_h_

#include "base.h"

class Derived : public Base{
public:
  Derived();
  void run();
  void start();
  ~Derived() ;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Instead of attempting to describe your code, please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us. Also please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Please show a [mcve] instead of describing code. It will highlight your issue much better. It's near impossible to reason about code we've never seen.

Comment: The solution:  don't include `derived.h` from `base.h`.

Comment: Why exactly do you need `friend class Derived;` if your `Base` class doesn't have any `private` fields?

Comment: @Kaldrr This isn't my exact code, only an example, so I didn't put all members of a class, only the ones I thought are relevant to the problem... There is a private field in Base class that I need access to from Derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical *circular dependency*. The `Base` class doesn't need the full definition of `Derived`, only know that it exists. This is done through *forward declarations*.

With a proper forward declaration, the `base.h` header file doesn't need to include the `derived.h` header file:

```
//File: base.h
#ifndef _base_h_
#define _base_h_

// Do not include header file for Derived
// Only do forward declaration
class Derived;    

class Base {
public:

void start();
void waitToComplete();
virtual ~Base();

static void sleep(Time timeToSleep);

protected:

friend class Derived;
Base ();
virtual void run() {}
};

#endif
```

---

On a couple of unrelated notes:

- The `Base::run` function should probably be a *pure* virtual function:

  ```
  virtual void run() = 0;
  ```
- Should the `Derived` class really override the `start` function?
- If you're overriding functions in a derived class, you should use the `override` special modifier identifier:

  ```
  void run() override;
  ```

Comment: I have tried that before, but it didn't help since I didn't realise I had other header files included that also had derived.h file included in them... When I fixed that, everything built just fine. Thank you so much!

Comment: The base header is given to us for a school project (base class is actually class Thread that we need to implement), so we are not supposed to change that. The Derived class is mine, so I will add the override modifier, thank you for pointing that out!